# snapd package manager problem in ubuntu 16.04 , how to resolve?

Tags: package-management, systemd, snap

```
After this operation, 33.0 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 329734 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing snapd (2.21~14.04) ...
Failed to stop snapd.autoimport.service: Unit snapd.autoimport.service not loaded.
dpkg: error processing package snapd (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 5
Failed to get unit file state for snapd.refresh.timer: No such file or directory
snapd.refresh.timer is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
Failed to get unit file state for snapd.autoimport.service: No such file or directory
snapd.autoimport.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 snapd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: What are you doing with a trusty (14.04) backport package in xenial (16.04)?

Comment: Yeah. It is true, that this error appears when you install trusty snapd package in ubuntu xenial by a mistake.

Answer (score 8):

Add `exit 0` after shebang to `/var/lib/dpkg/info/snapd.prerm`.

Next remove a package `dpkg --purge --force-all snapd`.

Check you pkg sources for trusty `rgrep 'xenial' /etc/apt`, and remove all sources that my be correspond to inproper version of snapd.

Run `apt-get update`, and upgrade a system to be in consistent state.

Comment: works like a charm!

Comment: saved my day :)

Comment: Much useful information when debugging bad package installs.