# Unable to sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop --reinstall

Tags: package-management, 17.04

I installed some packages, to see a list of the installed packages see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45064053/unable-to-install-ruby-gem-unf-ext-0-7-4-on-ubuntu). I walked away from my desk, locked the computer and returned to a black screen, before logging in.

I searched Google and found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/297080/ubuntu-open-to-black-screen-with-blinking-cursor-after-upgrading-from-12-10-to-1) telling ,me to restart a service, so I ran `sudo service lightdm --full-restart` it opened to my login screen, input my password, and logged into a black screen with a Komodo icon on it and my mouse cursor. So I searched some more and found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/243043/after-logging-in-theres-a-black-screen-and-my-cursor-nothing-else-in-ubuntu) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/779595/ubuntu-16-04-lts-black-screen-after-login). Tried both of those and nothing happened.

So I'm assuming that I'm going to have to reinstall the Ubuntu desktop, or run from a backup. Only issue I'm having when running `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop --reinstall` is a bunch of `unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages`:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  ubuntu-desktop : Depends: software-center but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: ubuntu-sso-client but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: unity but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: bluez-alsa but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: empathy but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: firefox but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: gnome-disk-utility but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: gnome-orca but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: landscape-client-ui-install but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: pulse-audio-module-x11 but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: totem-mozilla but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: ttf-punjabi-fonts but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: vino but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

These all sound pretty important, and like they should probably be installed already, so my question is pretty simple, what in the heck am I suppose to do now? How can I fix this successfully?

Comment: Wow what a mess, not really sure why you thought reinstalling the desktop would be of any help. At any rate run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -f` If you still have problems post any error messages.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I was out of ideas lol

Comment: @bodhi.zazen `dpkg: error processing package send snapd (--configure)` also `subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1` next line `Errors were encountered while processing: snapd`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First clear cache by `sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get clear cache` and then type `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`.
I think this will definitely gonna work.

Comment: I'll give it a shot here in a few minutes, thank you.

Comment: `apt-get upgrade` is, like the name suggests, for upgrading installed packages. It will not effect the troubleshooting of these dpkg installing errors. Also someone already suggested `apt-get update` in the comments of the question.

Comment: First command `errors were encountered while processing snapd sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned error code (1)` second command `dpkg: error processing package send snapd (--configure)` also `subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1` next line `Errors were encountered while processing: snapd`

Comment: I think you have problem with package snapd. I will  also faced same problem but with postfix package. At that time i removed the package postfix and this will helped for me.

Comment: I don't think that's it especially since it's literally telling me that `dpkg` is failing with error code 1

Comment: First you have to look at your both errors. They are encountered because of `snapd` package. So you have to do something about `snapd`.

Comment: I think removing or reinstalling will be the best option. You can follow this https://askubuntu.com/questions/877543/snapd-package-manager-problem-in-ubuntu-16-04-how-to-resolve

Comment: @IamDev That's what I ended up doing, it's installing right now

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who finds this thread and is having a similar problem. I ended up just rebooting into the Linux installer from a USB and reinstalling Ubuntu over the top of the corrupted installation. I still am not sure why this happened, what caused it, or how to *fix* it. I will update this answer if I happen to find any more information on it.

Answer (score -2):

Replaced the sources.list with new one

apt-get dist-upgrade

and then

apt-get install ubuntu-desktop

now it works fine

Comment: What is new one? What did you replace it with? Please use proper formatting (comment again if you want to know more)