# apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop

Tags: 18.04, dependencies, reinstall

First I would like to note, my problem is similar to this but the response didn't work. [Unable to sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop --reinstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/935554/unable-to-sudo-apt-get-install-ubuntu-desktop-reinstall)

When I run `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-server`, I get

```
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntu-server : Depends: byobu but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: curl but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: ubuntu-cloudimage-keyring but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: vim
                 Recommends: lxd but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When I try to install these packages, take vim for example, I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vim : Depends: vim-common (= 2:7.4.1689-3ubuntu1.4) but 2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**If I have apt ignore these dependencies for the reinstallation, will the reinstallation finish? or this Can Not work and Needs to be done manually?**

Please let me know if there is anything you would like me to try or clarify.

Comment: "sudo apt update" and "sudo apt upgrade " might help you to install the ubuntu-server successfully.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1249244/edit) to show us the complete output of `sudo apt update`. Looks like your underlying problem is the same, but your specifics are different. Solving Held Broken Packages requires understanding the conflict; shell incantations rarely work because the specifics are *always* different.