# apt upgrade: Failed to execute operation: No such file or directory

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, upgrade, updates

After upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04 apt-get got somehow messed up on my `xenial` system and I'm not sure how to fix it. This what I get (after `apt update`).
Can anyone offer some advice on how to fix this?

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libsimgearcore3.4.0v5 libsimgearscene3.4.0v5 linux-headers-4.4.0-97 linux-headers-4.4.0-97-generic linux-image-4.4.0-97-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-97-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Setting up snapd (2.28.5~14.04) ...
Failed to execute operation: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package snapd (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 snapd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've also tried to run `apt -f install` and got the following:

```
$ sudo apt -f install
[sudo] password for ron: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libsimgearcore3.4.0v5 libsimgearscene3.4.0v5 linux-headers-4.4.0-97 linux-headers-4.4.0-97-generic linux-image-4.4.0-97-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-97-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up snapd (2.28.5~14.04) ...
Failed to execute operation: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package snapd (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 snapd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

where `$ sudo dpkdg --configure -a` gives me:

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up snapd (2.28.5~14.04) ...
Failed to execute operation: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package snapd (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 snapd
```

Where `sudo apt-get --remove purge snapd` returns:

```
$ sudo apt-get --remove purge snapd
[sudo] password for ron: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  cgroup-lite libsimgearcore3.4.0v5 libsimgearscene3.4.0v5 linux-generic-lts-xenial linux-headers-4.4.0-97 linux-headers-4.4.0-97-generic linux-image-4.4.0-97-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-97-generic squashfs-tools
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  snapd*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 74.5 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 661915 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing snapd (2.28.5~14.04) ...
Failed to stop snapd.autoimport.service: Unit snapd.autoimport.service not loaded.
Failed to stop snapd.socket: Unit snapd.socket not loaded.
Failed to stop snapd.service: Unit snapd.service not loaded.
dpkg: error processing package snapd (--purge):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 5
Errors were encountered while processing:
 snapd
sudo aE: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Try running `apt-get -f install` and [edit] your question to include the output if it fails.

Comment: @dobey yes, i've tried that too, see above...

Comment: The line `dpkg: error processing package snapd (--configure)`. Means that `dpkg` experienced an error while trying to `--configure` the package `snapd`. Replacing the `snapd --configure` command and output in your question with the output of `sudo dpkg --configure -a` may be useful. You could take a look through the logs vi `journalctl`.

Comment: @J.Starnes Thanks I did that, please see above.

Comment: @cerr are you intentionally trying to install the trusty-updates version instead of the xenial-updates? If your system is xenial instead of trusty. You likely have a repo list issue. `lsb_release -a` will output your release info.

Comment: @cerr Did you install snapd on 14.04 and then later upgrade to 16.04?

Comment: @dobey exactly, that is what happemed, i don't need it anymore so could get rid of it...

Comment: @J.Starnes no, that is not intentional... but the package got installed with trusty as dobey correctly suggested

Comment: What happens if you run `sudo apt-get --remove purge snapd` then?

Comment: @dobey I've updated the result in the original post on top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/879065/723193) by @vskubriev may hold the key to forcing the removal.

Essentially:
Add `exit 0` after the shebang to `/var/lib/dpkg/info/snapd.prerm`. Then run the following commands.

```
dpkg --purge --force-all snapd
apt-get update
```

Optionally re-install by running `apt-get install snapd`

If @vskubriev's answer helps upvote it there not here.

Comment: really? Wow, this is cool, I didn't know about these rm scripts! Thanks!

Comment: neither did I until I researched your question. That is one of the reasons I stick around on stackexchange sites.

Answer (score 0):

As it looks like you've upgraded from 14.04 with snapd installed, to 16.04, and for some reason the snapd package did not get replaced, leaving you with this problem, you can perform the following to remove the package:

```
#: sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/snapd.p*rm
#: sudo apt-get remove --purge snapd
```

This will delete the pre/post removal scripts, and should allow the package to then be removed as the script is failing. If you do need snapd (because you've installed some snaps previously or such), you can just run:

```
#: sudo apt update
#: sudo apt install snapd
```