# how to fix Snapd dpkg error?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg

when i make `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` this early morning for my new kernel `4.4.0-131-generic`. i get my snapd error.

```
Setting up snapd (2.34.2~14.04) ...  
Failed to enable unit: Unit file snapd.autoimport.service does not exist.
dpkg: error processing package snapd (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of snapd-xdg-open:
snapd-xdg-open depends on snapd (= 2.34.2~14.04); however:
Package snapd is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package snapd-xdg-open (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 snapd
 snapd-xdg-open
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

i don't know how i do, i tried
sudo dpkg -a --configure
&&
sudo apt purge snapd*
&&
sudo apt-get remove snapd*

this not solved to me!! also i try to clear all cache on my Ubuntu and reinstall snapd, it's not fixed.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/877543/snapd-package-manager-problem-in-ubuntu-16-04-how-to-resolve (but adjust it to 18.04)

Comment: Thanks @Rinzwind his use xenial ubuntu sir, while i use trusty sir

Comment: The version does not matter; you just got to adjust the commands to "trusty" if there is any numbering involved.

Comment: @Rinzwind yeah your right sir, when i checking, i found xenial package on my trusty, wait a minute sir

Comment: @Rinzwind it's solved with clear xenial package sir, thanks

Comment: cool! glad you got it working. These problems can be annoying.

Comment: @Rinzwind Thanks a lot sir, please checked my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solved it,

**First Step**
Check all package source using:

```
rgrep 'xenial' /etc/apt
```

cause i used trusty instead xenial, so i remove all sources that of snapd* using

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r 'deb [some link xenial] xenial Release or inRelease'
```

**Next Step**

and i can purge and remove snapd to solved that.

```
dpkg --purge --force-all snapd
sudo apt install --fix-broken
```

run `sudo apt-get update`,after updated it's solved to me.